# how to repair windows 10 installation that I can't boot into using another installation on another partition

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I have an installation of windows 10 on c: and another on d:.  I'm unable to boot into the one on d: and would like to recover it with apps and stuff so I can forego the hassle of reinstalling apps, licenses, everything.  When on the installation on d:, it recognizes itself as being on c:. I'm currently only able to boot into the one on c: and was wondering how I can perform a repair install or something to the installation on d:.  Thank you.

Comment: c: and d: mean nothing. try again with using drive number and partition location if you can.  For instance.. "I have two drives with default partitions and the windows installation on drive 2 works but the one on drive 1 does not"..  We can give you better advice that way.  Also.. knowing desktop vs laptop allows whoever helps you to be more creative.

Comment: At boot time, regardless of disk or partition on which OS image resides after booting on, partition with his system files(Windows folder) will allways be marked as the C:\  partition. You boot to Windows OS on the HDD1 it will say I'm on the C:\ partition, you boot to the Windows OS on the HDD2 again He will say I'm on the C:\ partition.

Answer (score -1):

If your second OS, one to which you are not able to boot has no problems.
Next steps, I believe, are the simplest solution:

1. Boot into Windows RE or Windows PE environment and open up the CMD
2. run **`diskpart`**
3. When you enter into diskpart dialog run **`list volume`**
4. note your partitions and type **`exit`**
5. run **`C:\`**
6. run **`dir`** just to make sure you are on the partition with **Windows** folder on it
7. run **windows\system32\bcdboot w:\windows** to create a boot entry for your second OS
   in my example, "w:\windows" is the location of your second OS you have to determine what's the right path to it on your maschine
8. After restart, on every startup, you should be able to choose to which OSs you want to boot